# Next JS does not identify GSAP plugin module added via cdn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, gsap, scrolltrigger

I'm trying to use a gsap plugin module via cdn in my Next JS project.
So i started adding Script tags inside the Head tag in my _document.js
This is my code:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import Script from "next/script";
export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <Script
          src={
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js"
          }
          strategy="beforeInteractive"
        />
        <Script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/gsap.min.js"
          strategy="beforeInteractive"
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

Then i tried to use ScrollTrigger inside my index.jsx, like this:

```
 ScrollTrigger.addEventListener("scrollEnd", () =>
    console.log("scrolling ended!")
  );
```

But i'm getting this error:

ReferenceError: ScrollTrigger is not defined

I'm not a CDN user, but in GSAP docs this is what they recommend. Since sometimes it has instant load, and it has a great amount of users.
I've already read the next js docs. That's why i added these Script tags. But i am still getting this error...[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOvWn.png)

Comment: Can you show the component where you are calling ScrollTrigger.addEventListener?